# How to add a mask of the Russian phone number +7 (___) ___-__-__?

Tags: mask, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am interested in how to add a mask of a Russian phone number in the format
`+7 (___) ___-__-__`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Custom" option, then set the mask value to `+7 (999) 999-99-99`